# download/open "phtml' instead of opening the page, apache2

Tags: apache, drupal, ubuntu, apache2, php

I'm attempting to install drupal, as per the instructions found here:
http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=2381

when it comes to starting the drupal installation by visiting the 127.0.0.1/drupal to continue the installation, I am prompted with a popup to either open or download the PHTML index file.

the end of my apache2.conf file looks like this:
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions there are strange and includes unnessesary changes to the config files. I assume one or more of these changes caused your apache to break.

All you need, is a simple and clean LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP, on which any php-aplication, drupal too, will run) installation. I have found [howtoforge Lamp for Newbies](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies) a helpfull and solid resource for people new to LAMP.

I suggest your clean up all the packages you installed, remove left-over files (apt-get uninstall --prune might still leave files yout edited manually) and start from scratch using the LAMP instructions from Howtoforge.

Answer (score 0):

not sure it'll help but make sure you reload apache i have found with phpmyadmin that it sometimes tries to download the php file and an apache reload will fix it.